Kafka batch consumer not consuming latest 1 message from the partition
I have a .Net core kafka consumer, having batch consumer of batch size:- 100 and batch delay of 5 sec. The problem here is my consumer group Id gets stuck on the second last offset of each partition on the kafka topic. Since no any new messages were available in the topic the consumer is not processing the latest message in the partitions.
This is the configuration of the consumer
{ new KeyValuePair<string, string>("group.id", <groupname>), new KeyValuePair<string, string>("bootstrap.servers", <server>), new KeyValuePair<string, string>("enable.auto.commit", "false"), new KeyValuePair<string, string>("auto.offset.reset", "earliest"), new KeyValuePair<string, string>("retries", "0"), new KeyValuePair<string, string>("batch.num.messages", "100"), new KeyValuePair<string, string>("socket.nagle.disable", "true"), new KeyValuePair<string, string>("queue.buffering.max.ms", "0"), new KeyValuePair<string, string>("partition.assignment.strategy","roundrobin"), new KeyValuePair<string, string>("auto.commit.interval.ms","0"), new KeyValuePair<string, string>("max.poll.interval.ms","300000"), new KeyValuePair<string, string>("heartbeat.interval.ms", "3000"), new KeyValuePair<string, string>("session.timeout.ms", "30000") }
This is the consumer group lag that got stuck in this position for hours
enter image description here
I had update the config values.
